# Why am I getting SIGABRT?

Tags: c, sigabrt

```c
// Sort the given numbers in non decreasing order
// such that even and odd numbers are alternatively
// fit inside the array.

#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t;

    t  = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b =  t;
}

void sort(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                swap(arr + j, arr + j + 1);
}

void print_arr(int* arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void rearrange(int* arr, int size)
{
    // have two arrays to store odds and evens
    int odds[size], evens[size];
    int i, j, k;

    // sort the array
    sort(arr, size);

    // populate the two arrays
    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2) odds[j++] = arr[i];
        else evens[k++] = arr[i];
    }

    print_arr(odds, j);
    print_arr(evens, k);

    // check the first elements of `odds` and `evens`
    // in order to decide which ones occupy
    // the odd and even indices
    int* first;
    int* second;

    if (odds[0] < evens[0]) 
    {
        first = odds;
        second = evens;
    } else {
        first = evens;
        second = odds;
        swap(&j, &k);
    }

    // populate the odd and even indices of `res`
    i = 0;
    while (j >= 0)
    {
        arr[i] = first[--j];
        i += 2;
    }

    i = 1;
    while (k >= 0)
    {
        arr[i] = second[--k];
        i += 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = { 80, 54, 0, 9, 6, 5, 4, 67, 1}; // SIGABRT
    // int nums[] = { 80, 54, 9, 5, 4, 67, 1};
    rearrange(nums, 9);
    print_arr(nums, 9);
    return 0;
}
```

This runs just fine, but throws a SIGABRT **after** it actually prints out the result. This did not happen in any other cases that I tried. From the debug session, I could see that it works fine till the completion of `print_arr`, but after it returns to `main`, throws a SIGABRT, that's after it's actually printed out the result onto the console. I have not been able to figure out why.

Debugger Output:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f01 odd_even`main at odd_even.c:89:5
   86       int nums[] = { 80, 54, 0, 9, 6, 5, 4, 67, 1}; // SIGABRT
   87       // int nums[] = { 80, 54, 9, 5, 4, 67, 1};
   88       rearrange(nums, 9);
-> 89       print_arr(nums, 9);
   90       return 0;
   91   }
   92
Target 0: (odd_even) stopped.
(lldb)
80 67 54 9 6 5 4 1 0
Process 2580 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff6be8249a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x7fff6be8249a <+10>: jae    0x7fff6be824a4            ; <+20>
    0x7fff6be8249c <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff6be8249f <+15>: jmp    0x7fff6be7c3b7            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff6be824a4 <+20>: retq
Target 0: (odd_even) stopped.
```

You can see that I did get the output, but got the signal, after that.

Comment: why pass 7 when the size is 9?

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica I forgot to update the size, because I was testing the other array, but the problem exists when the size is passed correctly, I'll edit the code, thanks!

Comment: For k==0 and j==0 in `rearrange`, `second[--k]` and `first[--j]` are undefined.

Comment: @DYZ I have added the Debug Info.

Comment: @DYZ Got it, I just had to make them `>` from `>=` after I used the predecrement. Thank you!

Comment: The SIGABRT results when auto-generated code detects that a special data structure known as a stack canary has been corrupted. This check isn't guaranteed to happen right away, so the abort might be delayed relative to the mistake which causes the failure. According to my testing with `-fsanitize=address` in ASAN, the error happens as early as `rearrange`, but the damage isn't detected until `main` attempts to return.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-ζ-- Yes, that's what got me a little confused. Thank you so much for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *populate the odd and even indices of `res`*, your loops run when `j` or `k` are zero.  This causes the assignments `arr[i] = first[--j];` and `arr[i] = second[--k];` to access outside the bounds of the allocated space when accessing elements `first[-1]` and `second[-1]`.  However, the big problem this causes is that you are writing two additional elements to `arr`, which is also undefined behavior.  In this instance, this will corrupt the stack back in the caller (`main`), which results in the crash when `main` returns.